# Missing .git directory

Tags: git, github

I just started learning Git and I want to create a project named duldul so I run following commands first time.

```
$ mkdir duldul.git

$ cd duldul.git

$ git init

initialized empty GIT repository in c:/user/myname/duldul.git/.git
```

But the problem is "No folder with name .git exists in c:/user/myname/duldul.git". What is the problem?

Comment: Even hidden, he should still be able to view the contents of the folder.

Comment: Also note, your project folder does not need to have a `.git` extension

Answer (score 11):

`.git` is a hidden folder.  You will need to view hidden folders in your OS of choice to see it.

If you try to view the contents of the folder and get an error, try the `git init` again.